# How to export the registry file using the Inno Setup?

Tags: export, registry, inno-setup

```
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Product\Backup"; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: "BackRegPath"; ValueData: "C:\XPTUBACKUP"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Product"; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: "InstalledPath"; ValueData: "{app}\"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
Root: HKLM; Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Product\Backup"; ValueType: string; \
  ValueName: "BackTimeFmt"; ValueData: "000000"; Flags: uninsdeletevalue
```

Answer (score 0):

Inno Setup does not support that natively. But you can run [`reg export` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-export) to do the export.

```
[Run]
FileName: "reg"; \
  Parameters: "export ""HKLM\SOFTWARE\Product"" ""C:\come\path\Product.reg"" /y"
```